# WireGuard Lan access does not work on Linux but on Mobile phone

Tags: networking, fedora, manjaro, vpn, wireguard

I'm trying to connect my Laptop (which is running fedora or manjaro) to connect all the time to my raspberry Pi with PiVPN.
I have set up the IP tables and also port forwarding.

I can access my Pi under 10.6.0.1 but not my normal subnet 192.168.0.0/24. On my mobile phone I can access my Local Lan from other networks, but not from my laptop.

I've generated the wg0.conf wireguard file from PiVPN and put it under /etc/wireguard. And it is working. But I can't access the Lan. It should route all traffic through the Pi.

I've tried adding more to the Allowed IPs but this did'nt helped either. I also added IP Tables in the conf file. Is it a problem with the OS or Wireguard?

I also can ping 10.6.0.1 (PI) from another network while being connected over WireGuard, but when I try to ping 196.168.178.35 (LAN PI) it says couldn't reach host.

Conf files:
Pi Server:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <private>
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
MTU = 1420
ListenPort = <port>
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = <pubkey>
PresharedKey = <presharedkey>
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.4/32
```

Client:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <privatekey>
Address = 10.6.0.4/24
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
 PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
DNS = 10.6.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = <publickey>
PresharedKey = <sharedkey>
Endpoint = <my-external-ip>:<port>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive=30
```

Answer (score 0):

`AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` in your client WireGuard config means all traffic without an explicit route will be sent through that WireGuard peer. So you probably need to add an explicit route for your Pi's LAN address (or the subnet on which it lives).

On your laptop, run this:

```
$ ip route
```

The output will look something like this:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
10.6.0.0/24 dev wg0 scope link
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.123 metric 100
```

If you don't see a route that applies to your Pi's LAN address, add it, routing it through your laptop's default gateway; something like this:

```
$ sudo ip route add 192.168.178.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

---

Unrelated to that: you can remove the PostUp/PostDown iptables rules you have listed in your *client* WireGuard config, they're not doing anything for you (those rules apply only on servers that forward packets to other hosts -- that's why you have them in your Pi server's config).